# Control Multiple Ardrones in simulator

Tags: ros, tum-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I really wonder, if anyone figured out how to control multiple Ardrones.
I know How to spawn Multiple of them, but I still couldn't figure out how to control them.
The bad thing is that as soon as I spawn one more, Ardrone lost the control and takes off forever.
If anyone finds how to control them, could anyone please post it or comment?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173763/control-multiple-ardrones-in-simulator/) by [Yonggun Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/18859/yonggun-lee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-06-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know about tum_simulator, but with actual ARDrones the issue may be with duplicate IP addresses between the two drones. I don't have two drones to mess around with though, so I can't test or confirm any of this.

The ARDrone SDK says the following:

The AR.Drone 2.0 can be controlled from any client device supporting Wifi. The following
process is followed :

1. the AR.Drone creates a WIFI network with an ESSID usually called adrone2_xxx (ardrone_xxx for AR.Drone 1.0 ) and self allocates a free, odd IP address (typically 192.168.1.1).
2. the user connects the client device to this ESSID network.
3. the client device requests an IP address from the drone DHCP server.
4. the AR.Drone DHCP server grants the client with an IP address which is:

   the drone own IP address plus 1 (for AR.Drone 1.0 prior to version 1.1.3)

   the drone own IP address plus a number between 1 and 4 (for AR.Drone 2.0 and AR.Drone 1.0 after 1.1.3 version)
5. the client device can start sending requests the AR.Drone IP address and its services ports

---

Originally posted by [mechanicalmanb](https://answers.ros.org/users/15411/mechanicalmanb/) with karma: 86 on 2014-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yonggun Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/18859/yonggun-lee/) on 2014-07-23**:
Thank you for answering.
This answer is about one PC to multiple Ardrones right?

Actually I could be able to control Ardrone in Tum_simualtor while I spawn 2nd Ardrone.
Right now, I am working on to control 2nd ardrone.

Anyway, your answer will be good help when I start with Actual Hardware

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-02-03**:
@Yonggun Lee - How did you do it in tum_simulator ?